# Recursive Query To Identify Levels of Warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-server-2008-r2

Sql Server 2008

I have Tables like below

**location_tbl**

```
locid   locname
-----------------
019136  Hyderabad
119137  Vijayawada
219137  Mumbai
319137  Bangalore
```

**warehouse_tbl**

```
wh_id   whname               whaddr                    whdesc   locid
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
020143  Attapur Branch       Attapur, Hyderabad        Desc     019136
120149  Medchal Warehouse    Medchal, Hyderabad        Desc     019136
2221144 Hardware Store       Store, Mumbai             Desc     219137
```

**WH_Locations**

```
whLocId  whLocName      whLocDesc   parentId    wh_id
------------------------------------------------------
149     WHS1                        0            020143
150     Sec1                        149          020143
151     Sec2                        149          020143
152     Slot1                       149          020143
154     Sec2Sub1                    151          020143
155     Warehouse1                  0            120149
157     Warehouse2                  0            120149
158     Store1                      157          120149
159     Store2                      157          120149
161     WHS2                        0            2221144
152     Sec2Sub2                    154          020143
```

**Expected Results**

```
whLocId    whname   WH_Name           Sec_Name1  Sec_Name2  Sec_Name3  Sec_Name4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
149     Hyderabad   Attapur Branch    WHS1        NULL      NULL         NULL        
155     Hyderabad   Medchal Warehouse Warehouse1  NULL      NULL         NULL
157     Hyderabad   Medchal Warehouse Warehouse2  NULL      NULL         NULL
161     Mumbai      Hardware Store    WHS2        NULL      NULL         NULL
152     Hyderabad   Attapur Branch    WHS1        Slot1     NULL         NULL
154     Hyderabad   Attapur Branch    WHS1        Sec2    Sec2Sub1 NULL                         
158     Hyderabad   Medchal Warehouse Warehouse2  Store2    NULL         NULL
159     Hyderabad   Medchal Warehouse Warehouse2  Store2    NULL         NULL         
150     Hyderabad   Attapur Branch    WHS1        Sec1      NULL         NULL         
151     Hyderabad   Attapur Branch    WHS1        Sec2      NULL         NULL 
154     Hyderabad   Attapur Branch    WHS1        Sec2    Sec2Subsub1  Sec2Sub2
```

Tried Some thing like

```
`SELECT    distinct c.whLocId ,a.locname, b.whname, d.whLocName AS Sec_name1,   c.whLocName     AS Sec_Name2,
e.whLocName AS Sec_Name3,f.whLocName AS Sec_Name4
FROM         dbo.location_tbl AS a INNER JOIN
                  dbo.warehouse_tbl AS b ON a.locid = b.locid INNER JOIN
                  dbo.WH_Locations AS c ON b.wh_id = c.wh_id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.WH_Locations AS d ON c.parentId = d.whLocId inner join
                  dbo.WH_Locations AS e on d.whlocid= e.parentid INNER JOIN
 dbo.WH_Locations AS f on f.whlocid= e.whlocid 
`
```

But not working..getting some success to bind first two columns but not the recirsive one

also column name should be bound by output i mean the last level. Also need to keep null after the level ends until the last level.

Any help,hint will be helpful

Thanks

Let me know if any issue with Font etc will edit it..

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that you only want to have a maximum of 4 sections or are you specifically looking for a solution that will accommodate a dynamic amount of sections?

Comment: @KHeaney Heaney Ideally i'm looking to have Sec_NameN where N is the last level.In above output Sec2Sub2 is at 4th level thus we have Sec_Name4. Even without a Dynamic column too it will work if have a Query with Hard coded Column name, later will figure out how can i add a dynamic column. Thanks